# how to do stack permutations of a sequence of numbers

Tags: stack, permutation

is it possible to obtain the following permutations of 123456 using a stack?
1. 325641 2. 154623 3. 143562

My step for example for 1:

push 1 push 2 push 3 pop 3 pop 2 push 4 push 5 pop 5 push 6 pop 6 pop 4 pop 1

so it is possible for 1

Is it the way to do it? Or am i wrong in my steps?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't appear to be a programming question.

Comment: Of course is this possible since you are just re-stacking that stack. Question answered?

Comment: @StefanR.Falk He didn't say "is it possible", he said "it *is* possible" (for 1). Number 2 is not possible. Number 3 is possible. Presumably you're supposed to see the general pattern that makes it possible/impossible. Although the question is not well-described. Is every pop automatically a print, too?

Comment: @oli this cannot be off topic...thousands of questions here which is not pure programming but relates to concepts of computer science

Comment: if anyone of you could also help me in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23297475/mex-position-in-state-graph it would be much appreciated

Comment: If you have a computer-science question, then http://cs.stackexchange.com might be the right place.  But you don't have a CS question, you have a "how do I solve this puzzle?" question.